# What does two font sizes mean in this css

Tags: css, fonts

I came across the following css:

`font: 300 24px/30px Roboto, sans-serif;`

What do the two font sizes mean (24px/30px)? I'm use to seeing only one size.

Comment: Did you read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Obviously they did not. I don't get how people find it easier to ask a question here over reading basic docs.

Comment: It's not easier. It's faster! Not to mention that it gives someone some nice points.

Comment: Remember about it: https://snag.gy/BgT5pM.jpg - that's the reason for example that you will not see the difference between .font and .font3 in this code: https://jsfiddle.net/kademat/5qwzps8e/4/ May be important for better understanding the topic :)

Comment: Faster only if you don't know what or where to look for. Sadly true, usually the simplest solutions/explanations to simple issues get the most votes because the audience who understand it, is greater. Typically those and others with less experience are the ones who upvote the most, i.e. their "evaluation criteria" is low, but for me it's pretty funny that the answer below got so much/many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one (`24px`) is the `font-size`. The second (`30px`) is the `line-height`.

You can see more examples of that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)